# Filter ul list through JavaScript not properly filtering through list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a filter list for an ul, but my JavaScript function doesn't appear to take the input and filter through the list. I'm not exactly sure why that's happening. I have also attempted to change the for loop as `for (i = 0; i < ul.length; i++)`, to search through the ul, but it doesn't seem to respond that either.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myMovies" onkeyup="searchTitle()" placeholder="Is your movie on here?">
        <ul id="movieList">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
        </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function searchTitle(){
    var input, filter,  ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myMovies");
    filter = input.nodeValue.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("movieList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a"[0]);
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexof(filter) > -1) {
            li[a].style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            li[a].style.display = "Not found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a"[0]);`?

Comment: begin each test list item with a different letter. Pay attention to what DOM element has focus, or what level of DOM event(s) you are listening to. `.keyup` is the right event listener though, so your getting close.

Comment: Typo with getElementsByTagName("a"[0])?

Comment: You have a lot of errors. I would suggest learning to use a debugger or browser console. Some examples: you can't index `li` by `a`. There is no function `indexof`. There is no `nodeValue` for `input`. You can't index a string `"a"[0]`. You have no `a` tags in your HTML. `"Not found"` is not a valid value for `style.display`.

Comment: I originally had a tags in the elements, but I deleted them and forgot to modify the code. I don't know why I had so many typos, though, I guess I should double check my work better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was a typo on the line where you had `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a"[0]);`, maybe you wanted to do `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that accomplishes what you seem to be attempting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function searchTitle(){
    var input, filter,  ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myMovies");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      window.status = filter;
    ul = document.getElementById("movieList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        a = li[i];
        if (a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a.style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            a.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
<input type="text" id="myMovies" onkeyup="searchTitle()" placeholder="Is your movie on here?">
        <ul id="movieList">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
        </ul>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding the `window.status` helped. Thanks!